# Sublime Text 3 control panel undocumented error

Tags: python, sublimetext3, python-import

Putting together a new sublime install and trying to install the Control Panel. Have been through all of the standard forums, but just in the position of getting a mystery traceback regardless of installation method.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_plugin.py", line 74, in reload_plugin
   m = importlib.import_module(modulename)
 File "./importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1532, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "/opt/sublime_text/sublime_plugin.py", line 678, in load_module
   exec(compile(source, source_path, 'exec'), mod.__dict__)
 File "Package Control in /home/slater/.config/sublime-text-3/Installed Packages/Package Control.sublime-package", line 14, in <module>
 File "./posixpath.py", line 83, in join
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'
plugins loaded
Unable to open /home/slater/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Package Control/Package Control.sublime-settings
Unable to open /home/slater/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
Unable to open /home/slater/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings
```

Presumably, this traceback is why things aren't functional, but unfortunately it's completely impenetrable. It references code that doesn't exist that seems to be making a relative call to another file that doesn't exist. I tried opening up the `Package Control` zip file, but since the console isn't giving me a real traceback and there's no file called `posixpath.py` it's very unhelpful for debugging.

It seems like this is some issue with paths? The call to the sublime files in `opt` is also throwing me for a loop, but I'm not certain that's related the the problem I'm seeing.

UPDATE: Have tried adding sublime package files to $PATH and $PYTHONPATH. Have also experimented with permissions, all to no avail.